# Continuous Movement of gun bullet

Tags: box2d, andengine

I was using box2d for the movement of the body. When I apply gravity (0,0) the bullet continuously move but when I change gravity to the earth the behavior was changed. I also try to apply continuous force to the bullet body but the behavior was not so good. So please provide any suggestion to continuously move bullet body in earth gravity.

```
currentVelocity = bulletBody.getLinearVelocity();
if (currentVelocity.len() < speed|| currentVelocity.len() > speed + 0.25f) {
    velocityChange = Math.abs(speed - currentVelocity.len());
    currentVelocity.set(currentVelocity.x* velocityChange, currentVelocity.y*velocityChange);
    bulletBody.applyLinearImpulse(currentVelocity,bulletBody.getWorldCenter());
}
```

I apply above code for the continuous velocity of the body. And also I did not able to find any setGravityScale method in the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your andengine library for the gravity of the body.By implementing                            body.setGravityScale(0) 
method in the library the body does not feel any gravity from the physics world.

Answer (score 0):

Bullets are subject to gravity as well, they just usually move so fast that it doesn't matter. Are you trying to make something like a rocket that moves quite slowly but steadily across the screen?

You could go around the problem by continuously applying force equal and opposite to the gravity.

Comment: Yes I was making somewhat like rocket in my game. I apply continuous force equal and opposite gravity but that does not work for me and direction of the bullet was change.

Comment: After soom googleing it seems setting to body type to kinematic disables gravity for that body: body.type = b2_kinematicBody; Another option is setting the gravity scale for that body to zero: body->SetGravityScale( 0 )